# Using MySQL Workbench, is there a way to fill in missing dates and creating a new row with the last status that was filled

Tags: mysql, automation

I currently have a massive table of all status changes for a specific ID with the corresponding date, and multiple IDs have the same data. Currently the Table looks like

```
id  status  date
1 open 2020-06-21
1 closed 2020-06-24
2 open 2020-06-23
2 closed 2020-06-25
```

And I am trying to get to this. Filling in the dates with the last status .

```
id  status  date
1 open 2020-06-21
1 open 2020-06-22
1 closed 2020-06-23
2 open 2020-06-22
2 open 2020-06-23
2 closed 2020-06-24
```

This table is always going to be updating constantly so I'm unsure how to best store the information, maybe a separate view? I'm also looking into using a calendar tables but that doesn't seem to be the best solution(but if it is please tell me). Has anyone encountered a problem like this before and have a good solution that they have done in the past? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ' calendar tables but that doesn't seem to be the best solution; - I disagree.

Comment: How would you go about using a calendar table for this specific example if you were to use a calendar table while calling back to the last status?

Comment: Some thing to explain please. Why is the last expected output for id 2020-06-23 when your data has 2020-06-24 (and similarly for id 2), Do you want the last date for each id to stop on the first closed or continue for until the max date is reached over the entire record set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of mysql supports CTEs (quoting your version is useful when asking) then

```
WITH CTE as
(
select s.id,dt from dates 
cross join (select distinct id from t) s
where dt between (select min(date) from t where t.id = s.id) and (select max(date) from t where t.id = s.id)
)
select cte.id,cte.DT ,
        #t.id,t.DATE,t.status,
        coalesce(t.status,
        (select t1.status from t t1 
        where t1.id = cte.id and t1.date < cte.dt and t1.status is not null 
        order by t1.date desc limit 1)
        ) status
from cte
left join t on cte.dt = t.date and t.id = cte.id
order by cte.id,cte.dt;
```

Where dates is my calendar table.

The cte part grabs the date range for each id and the main query backfills by looking for the most recent non null status per id if required (coalesce)